# Vector of instances of a Class

Tags: c++, class, containers, copy-constructor

I am trying to create a vector of objects taken from a certain class i created but none of the constructors of that instances of the class are available

I have been trying several different constructors taken from the stl vectors (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) but none of them works

here's the class I have

```
class Digit{
public:
 //ctor 
  Digit():
    m_v(0),
    m_m(8)
    {};

  Digit(int m, int v):
    m_v(v),
    m_m(m)
    {};

  Digit(int v):
    m_v(v),
    m_m(8)
    {};

  //copyctor
  Digit(Digit& digit):
    m_v(digit.m_v),
    m_m(digit.m_m)
    {};

  //get-set
  int GetDigit(){return (m_v % m_m);};
  void SetV(int v){m_v=v; return;};
private:
  int m_v, m_m;
};
////// ==================Digit=============================/////
```

and here's the attempt to create a vector

```
Digit d(8,13);

  std::vector<Digit> vec(4,d);
```

Say i want to see the result of GetDigit() then expected result should be a sequence of the number 5

5 5 5 5

but for all constructors included in my class I get

candidate constructor not viable: 1st argument ('const Digit') would lose const qualifier

Comment: Try `Digit(const Digit& digit)` for your copy constructor. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor